# Eliminar archivos con Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

estoy intentando hacer una adaptación de bash (la terminal de Linux) en Windows, para esto estoy utilizando Python.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wt = True
    while wt:
        cmd = str(raw_input("{}>".format(os.getcwd())))
        if cmd == "help":
            print('''de momento no pondré este comando porque el output es largo''')
        elif cmd == "clear":
            subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","/c","cls"])
        elif cmd [:2] == "ls" and cmd[2:] == "":
            dirlist = os.listdir('.')

            for file in dirlist:
                print(file)

        elif cmd[:6] == "mkdir ":
            try:
                os.mkdir(cmd[6:])
            except Exception as e: 
                print("ese directorio ya existe") 
        elif cmd[:3] == "cd ":
            try:
                os.chdir(cmd[3:])
            except Exception as e:
                print("el sistema no puede encontrar la ruta")
        elif cmd[:3] == "rm":
            pass
```

el problema está en el comando `rm`, simplemente no se como hacerlo.
pensaba en poner `subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","/c","del (archivo)"])` pero se me iba a complicar de todas formas, porque en batch (cmd) se borran archivos y directorios con comandos distintos, entonces tendría que hacer que el programa identifique si es un directorio o un archivo.

¿como puedo borrar archivos con python?

O

¿como puedo hacer que python distinga si algo es un archivo o un directorio?

cualquiera de las 2 respuestas me va a ser útil, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, buscas implementar una funcionalidad bastante limitada del comando `rm`, básicamente borrar un archivo y no una carpeta. Podrías implementar algo así:

```
import os

def rm(path):

    if os.path.isdir(path):  
        print("Imposible borrar {0}!. Es una carpeta.".format(path))  
    elif os.path.isfile(path):  
        try:
            os.remove(path)
        except OSError, e:
            print ("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename,e.strerror))

    else:  
        print("Error. No se ha encontrado {0}.".format(path))
```

Para probarlo:

```
file_to_delete=raw_input("Ingrese el archivo a borrar: ")
rm(file_to_delete)
```

Detalle:

- Con [`os.path.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) determinamos si el `path` ingresado corresponde a una carpeta/directorio
- Con [`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) si es un archivo, en cuyo caso:
- [`os.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) eliminará el mismo. Nota que usamos una clausula `try/except` para controlar cualquier excepción del tipo `OSError`.

En la práctica [`os.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) emitirá una excepción del tipo `OSError` al intentar eliminar una carpeta, por lo podríamos evitar controlar si es un directorio y simplificar aún más la función:

```
def rm(path):

    try:
        os.remove(path)
    except OSError, e:
        print ("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename,e.strerror))
```

Comment: ¿Porqué importas "sys"? No veo donde se usa.

Comment: @diegomedina: "No veo donde se usa", y ves bien. Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Python posee métodos para realizar estas tareas como lo son [remove](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) y [rmdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir)

tambien posees funciones de utilidad como:

- [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) que te permite eliminar un arbol completo de directorio.

En general te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a la documentación de la librería estándar [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os), y recuerda la diferencia que existe entre los directorios de windows y linux '/' y '\'. utiliza las funciones de [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path#module-os.path) para que te evites problemas.

tambien **os.path** posee funciones para determinar si una ruta es de un directorio, un archivo o un link ( **isdir, isfile, islink** )